# Passing SQL queries as variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

is it possible to pass an SQL query from a locally stored database to a html/php doc. So for example could I pass "Select count adminID From administrator" to be displayed on my html page in a text box? If possible please advise, if any other methods I would be open to them.

Comment: the page would have to be php rather than html unless you have done some trickery with your webserver so it executes html pages as php. What do you mean by "pass" in this context - execute the query and display results in a text box?

Comment: yes sorry as a php page is what I mean, and exactly I basically wanna pass the query and display the results in a text box for now. Thanks. Is this possible or is there any other method I should be looking towards?

Comment: It is possible if I have understood correctly and very simple to do. If you haven't read the PHP manual about mysql, mysqli or PDO then you should do so ~ there are plenty of examples of how you connect to the database, how you execute a query and then, most importantly, how to output the response. Have a go - if you get stuck then post your code that you tried and no doubt you will get help

Comment: OK so I have tried numerous syntax and keep running into errors. I have this at the moment...(see below)
I don't receive any errors but the query doesn't seem to be correct as nothing is being echoed on the page.

Comment: <?php
    include "connect.php";
    
    $query = ("SELECT COUNT adminID FROM administrators");
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    
    echo "$result";
    
    
    ?>